# Figured I'd give you guys access to this puzzle

Tags: riddle, visual

Get the answer from these pictures by finding the associated word from each group.

[image]

Comment: There's an inconsistency; because that doesn't look like 'jumping', but that does look like a 'guitar'.

Comment: It's "Bungee  Jumping"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After almost two hours of racking my brain, I think I finally have it:

> Database!

First group:

> Data mining
>  Raw data (thanks @Silenus)
>  Data field
>  Bank data (or data bank, as suggested by @Silenus)

Second group:

> Military base
>  BASE jumping
>  Bass guitar
>  Bass fishing (according to OP, the clue is actually Base line)

The title:

> Database access; or Microsoft Access, a database program (suggested by @Sabre)

Comment: The meat clues *raw data*.

Comment: And the bank probably clues *data bank*, rather than *bank data*.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed it was raw meat but got hung up on the "meat" part.

Comment: The guitar is not of the specific type you are assuming it to be.

Comment: @jambjo I don't think that matters. The jumping in the picture above it isn't BASE jumping either, but the word association still works.

Comment: As for the title, Microsoft Access is a database program.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not 'jumping' either. :-(

Comment: Correct! Great work. Although I was going for "Baseline" with the fishing line clue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not but I think the answer is:

> [Groundline](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groundline)

The first group:

> A mine underground
>  [Ground beef](https://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2014/01/tortellini.jpg)
>  Grass ground
>  [Banking ground](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/banking_ground)

The second group:

> In the front line
>  [Jumping line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_line)
>  [Melodic line](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/melodic%20line)
>  [ANDE Fishing line](https://www.andemonofilament.com/store/line.html)

Comment: Some good connections but it's not the correct answer.